# how to pass a variable from one phtml to another?

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, variables, parameter

I have two phtml which have its own unique block file. I need to pass variable from one phtml to another.

**PHTML 1**

```
<?php 
$option_id = 20;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/brandsmodules/index/demo" ></a>
```

**PHTML 2**

In this page is where I need to get the variable. I don't want to pass variables in URL as parameter due to security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You can send variable in URL like this to pass variable in another .phtml

In your **PHTML 1**

```
<?php $option_id = 20; ?>

<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('brandsmodules/index/demo', ['optionId' => $option_id]) ?>
```

In your **PHTML 2**

And you will get your optionId in another phtml by using **$_GET['optionId']**.

Please check and let me know if any question.

Comment: @RameshKR does this work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setKey('dfd')->setTemplate("VendorName_ModuleName::fileName.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

print your value as

```
$block->getKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your block class add two method.

1. setCustomData
2. getCustomData

```
public function setCustomData($data)
{
    $this->registry->register('custom_data', $data);
}

public function getCustomData()
{
    return $this->registry->registry('custom_data');
}
```

From first phtml, you set data like:

```
$block->setCustomData(12);
```

and from 2nd phtml, you can get data like:

```
$data = $block->getCustomData();
```

add $this->registry using DI. For example:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

Comment: What if they are two different blocks?

Answer (score 0):

In the first phtml .You can set the data in this way

```
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(Vendor/ModuleName/Block/BlockFile::class)
    ->setTemplate("Vendor_ModuleName::template_file.phtml")
    ->setData('data', 10)
    ->toHtml() ?>
```

And In the second phtml ie (template_file.phtml) call the data in this way

```
 <?= $block->getData('data'); ?> //10
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding !!